# python pickle multiple writes concurrency concerns

Tags: python, pickle

My python program is using pickle to store object in file. I want to check if there are any concurrency issues I should be aware of with the following sequence of operations?

1. open pickle file
2. update pickle file with adding new entry or deleting existing entry
3. close pickle file

Thanks!!